# Anonymous type conversion issue with Entity Framework 4 and Web Api

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, asp.net-web-api

I am fleshing out my data access layer and have run into my first issue. I am using Entity Framework code first along with some repositories and asp.net web api to surface the data in json format.

I am trying to get data from two different poco's served up in a get method. The models are these:

```
public class Freelancer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public Address FreelancerAddress { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

and address:

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and finally the list of Client objects:

```
public class Client
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address ClientAddress { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public int FreelancerID { get; set; }
    public Freelancer Freelancer { get; set; }
}
```

In my Api Controller I am trying to do something like this (simplified for this question):

```
public IEnumerable<Freelancer> Get()
    {
        var user = Uow.Freelancers.GetFreelancer(1);
        var result = from x in user
                     select new
                     {
                         ID = x.ID,
                         Name = x.LastName,
                         Address = x.FreelancerAddress.Street
                     };
        return result;
    }
```

The error I get is this:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' 
>       to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. 
>       An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I can return just the Freelancer object just fine, but in the Json it will show null for address and clients, even though there is related data. Is there a way to get the objects I need using linq, or should I do some kind of re-design of my DAL. I am in the beginning stages so I am looking for a best practice suggestion if you have one.

***Additional Info***

This is what gets served up from Uow.Freelancer.GetFreelancer(1);

```
[{"iD":1,"email":"david.stanley.13@gmail.com","password":"password","firstName":"David","lastName":"Stanley","companyName":null,"avatar":null,"freelancerAddress":null,"clients":null}]
```

GetFreelancer() looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Freelancer> GetFreelancer(int id)
    {
        IEnumerable<Freelancer> freelancer = (from x in DbSet
                         select x);
        return freelancer;
    }
```

I don't see any way to use .Reference or .Include, but that may be the right track. I remember doing something like that a few projects ago...

**It works!!***

Here is what needed to happen:

I changed the GetFreelancer method to this:

```
IEnumerable<Freelancer> freelancer = from x in DbSet
                                     .Include("FreelancerAddress")
                                     .Include("Clients")
                                             where x.ID == id
                                             select x;

        return freelancer;
```

Which did not work at first because Freelancer was referencing Client which had a full reference to Freelance, so it tunnelled forever. I removed the reference in Client so it looks like this instead:

```
public class Client
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address ClientAddress { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public int FreelancerID { get; set; }
}
```

And my output is exactly what I needed: A freelancer and his address, with a list of his clients.

Comment: Change the `select new` in your LINQ statement to `select new Freelancer`.

Comment: Looks like that takes care of the error message, but still doesn't serve up the data I am looking for..

Comment: You may need to populate the data as well, within your LINQ statement.  I'm not 100% sure how to do that off the top of my head - hopefully someone here will see the question and provide more guidance.  If I get a chance I'll see what I can find.

Comment: The Clients collection, for example, is probably null by default - you'll need to tell the compiler what to set that property/collection to.  You should be able to do this through LINQ - there's something tickling the back of my brain about this but I can't recall it clearly at this moment.

Comment: I'll have to dig into that. Would it be better if I just combined the Freelancer and Address object together into one? I know I could eventually get into the clients on the view with a foreach statement..

Comment: Since the Address object isn't a collection (just a single instance) I don't see any problem rolling it into the Freelancer object.  That's a decision that ultimately will be driven by the design of your project, though.  Will you need more than one address instance in the future, for example?

Comment: Good insight. Too small of a project to really warrant a separate address model, can't imagine any need for multiple addresses in the future. I was having is separate so both the Freelancer and Client objects could have a full address without having to retype it all up.

Comment: I missed that part when I looked at your code.  That's a good approach, IMO (code reuse).  If you can figure out how to load the related data for Client, you'll be able to do the same thing for the address.  That way you can keep your design as is.

Comment: What does `Uow.Freelancers.GetFreelancer(1)` return?  Can you share the code?  I did a little googling, and it looks like you can use the `.Include` or `.Reference` extension methods to include related data.  [Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232).  The .include extension method was the one tickling the back of my mind earlier.

Comment: See my answer below - hopefully it will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: +1 for updating your original question with a detailed example of what ended up working out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried this code, this is simply off the top of my head based on the supplied code and what I've found via Google, but it will hopefully get you pointed in the right direction.

I think the change should be made in the `GetFreeLancer` method (in terms of getting the related tables).  I also noticed you weren't using the supplied id in the query, which means you're method as is is going to give you all the entries in the table, so I've added in a where clause in my example.

The basic idea I'm trying to convey here is that you load the Address and the Clients collection when you get the desired Freelancer record.  I'm assuming that DbSet is your context, and I'm guessing at the entity names.

```
public IEnumerable<Freelancer> GetFreelancer(int id)
{

    IEnumerable<Freelancer> freelancer = from x in DbSet.Freelancers
                                         .Include("Address")
                                         .Include("Client")
                                         where x.Id == id
                                         select x;

    return freelancer;
}
```

Once you have the proper data returning, you should be able to get whatever you need in your controller method.

Like I said, I haven't tried this code but at least hopefully it will get you going.

I would also suggest getting LINQPad, as it's a great tool for testing and playing around with LINQ queries.

Comment: Sweet! This got me one step of the way! I had to get rid of clients and it worked fine. I think my issue with clients is that the I have a circle reference that seems to go infinitely deep. I am going to try and remove the Freelance reference from the Client object as see where that goes

Comment: Got it to work based off of your answer, check my final edit (in a couple minutes) to see the working models. Thanks dude!

Comment: Awesome - I'm glad you got it to work.  And thanks for sharing the answer, as I'm sure others will encounter similar problems in the future.  Happy coding!